# Undelivered mails after using sp_send_dbmail and cursor

Tags: sql, database-cursor

I am inserting a query into the table. Then I open a cursor from that table. I send mail using sp_sen_dbmail with the information I get from the cursor.

I write different mail copy_recipients different mail for Recipients. One receives 34 mails and another 37 mails.

When I examine the logs, those whose sent_account_id returns NULL seem to have failed.

When I run the same procedure again, I see that it is sent to previously undelivered mails this time.

I am using function for mail address accuracy. Emails are correct. If it's wrong, I'm sending an e-mail to myself.

I also tried wait for delay but the problem is not solved.

There is an unstable situation such as 1 sending 2 not sending 4 sending 1 not sending.

the error I get is;

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2021-12-15T1701). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
```

I added my codes.

We checked with the friend at IT. He said that the mail to be sent is not sent to the exchange.

The problem said on the SQL side

I would appreciate your help.

```
----INSERT TABLE-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL ON;

INSERT INTO TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL 

--SELECT * INTO TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL FROM (

(
G.TARİH, G.[CLCARD LOGREF], G.[FİRMA KODU], G.[FİRMA ADI], G.MAIL, G.BCC, G.[firmamiz YETKİLİ], G.[firmamiz POZİSYON], G.[firmamiz İLETİŞİM TELEFONU], G.[firmamiz EPOSTA ADRESİ], 
G.[ORT. VADE], G.[ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ], G.[VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI], G.[VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ], G.[TOPLAM BORÇ BAKİYENİZ]
)

SELECT TOP 50
G.TARİH, G.[CLCARD LOGREF], G.[FİRMA KODU], G.[FİRMA ADI], G.MAIL, G.BCC, G.[firmamiz YETKİLİ], G.[firmamiz POZİSYON], G.[firmamiz İLETİŞİM TELEFONU], G.[firmamiz EPOSTA ADRESİ], 
G.[ORT. VADE], G.[ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ], G.[VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI], G.[VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ], G.[TOPLAM BORÇ BAKİYENİZ]
FROM 

(
SELECT
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AS 'TARİH',
CLCARD.LOGICALREF AS 'CLCARD LOGREF',
CLCARD.CODE AS 'FİRMA KODU',
CLCARD.DEFINITION_ AS 'FİRMA ADI',

--CASE 
--WHEN dbo.EmailKontrolEdenFonksiyon (CLCARD.EMAILADDR) <> 'DOĞRU' THEN 'gokhanerdogdu@firmamiz-.com' 
--ELSE CLCARD.EMAILADDR END AS 'MAIL',

'gokhanerdogdu@firmamiz-.com' AS 'MAIL',

'noreply@firmamiz-.com' AS 'BCC',




CASE
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '01' THEN '111'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '02' THEN '222'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '03' THEN '333'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '04' THEN '444'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '06' THEN '555'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '07' THEN '666'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '08' THEN '777'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '09' THEN '888'
END AS 'firmamiz YETKİLİ',

CASE
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '01' THEN 'İç Satış Sorumlusu'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '02' THEN 'İç Satış Sorumlusu'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '03' THEN 'Satış Mühendisi'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '04' THEN 'İç Satış Sorumlusu'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '06' THEN 'Satış Mühendisi'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '07' THEN 'İç Satış Sorumlusu'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '08' THEN 'İç Satış Sorumlusu'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '09' THEN 'İç Satış Mühendisi'
END AS 'firmamiz POZİSYON',

CASE
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '01' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '02' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '03' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '04' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '06' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '07' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '08' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
WHEN LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) = '09' THEN '+90 222 333 44 55'
END AS 'firmamiz İLETİŞİM TELEFONU',


'noreply@firmamiz-.com' AS 'firmamiz EPOSTA ADRESİ',


--ORT.VADE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(
SELECT
DATEADD (D, (SUM ((DATEDIFF (DD, GETDATE(), PAYTRANS.DATE_)) * PAYTRANS.TOTAL) / SUM (PAYTRANS.TOTAL) ), GETDATE())
FROM LG_215_01_PAYTRANS AS PAYTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
PAYTRANS.PAID = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.CANCELLED = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.CARDREF = CLCARD.LOGICALREF
) AS 'ORT. VADE',


--ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISNULL ((
SELECT
ROUND (SUM (ISNULL ((DATEDIFF (DD, GETDATE(), PAYTRANS.DATE_)) * ISNULL (PAYTRANS.TOTAL,0),0)) / SUM (PAYTRANS.TOTAL),0)
FROM LG_215_01_PAYTRANS AS PAYTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
PAYTRANS.PAID = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.CANCELLED = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.DATE_ < GETDATE()
AND PAYTRANS.CARDREF = CLCARD.LOGICALREF
),0) AS 'ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ',

--VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISNULL ((
SELECT 

SUM (ISNULL (CASE WHEN PAYTRANS.DATE_ < GETDATE() THEN (CASE WHEN PAYTRANS.SIGN = '0' THEN PAYTRANS.TOTAL ELSE PAYTRANS.TOTAL*-1 END) ELSE '0' END,0))
--SUM (ISNULL (CASE WHEN PAYTRANS.DATE_ < GETDATE() THEN PAYTRANS.TOTAL ELSE 0 END,0))

FROM LG_215_01_PAYTRANS AS PAYTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
PAYTRANS.CARDREF = CLCARD.LOGICALREF
AND PAYTRANS.PAID = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.CANCELLED = '0'
),0) AS 'VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI',

--VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISNULL ((
SELECT 

SUM (ISNULL (CASE WHEN PAYTRANS.DATE_ > GETDATE() THEN (CASE WHEN PAYTRANS.SIGN = '0' THEN PAYTRANS.TOTAL ELSE PAYTRANS.TOTAL*-1 END) ELSE '0' END,0))

FROM LG_215_01_PAYTRANS AS PAYTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
PAYTRANS.CARDREF = CLCARD.LOGICALREF
AND PAYTRANS.PAID = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.CANCELLED = '0'
),0) AS 'VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ',
----------------------------------------------------
ISNULL ((
SELECT 

SUM (ISNULL (CASE WHEN PAYTRANS.SIGN = '0' THEN PAYTRANS.TOTAL ELSE PAYTRANS.TOTAL*-1 END,0))

FROM LG_215_01_PAYTRANS AS PAYTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
PAYTRANS.CARDREF = CLCARD.LOGICALREF
AND PAYTRANS.PAID = '0'
AND PAYTRANS.CANCELLED = '0'
),0) AS 'TOPLAM BORÇ BAKİYENİZ'



FROM LG_215_CLCARD AS CLCARD WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE
LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) IN ('01', '02', '03', '04', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10')
--LEFT (CLCARD.CODE,2) IN ('07')
AND CLCARD.LOGICALREF NOT IN (
'19732',
'7056',
'26692',
'29604',
'24228',
'24887',
'28022',
'25826'
)


) AS G
WHERE
G.[VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI] > 1000
ORDER BY G.[FİRMA ADI]
--) AS GG
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL OFF;

END

--INSERT TABLE TO MAIL
BEGIN 

DECLARE @ODEME_TALEP_INSERT NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TOPLAM_SAYI NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @BODY_INSERT NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @KONU_INSERT NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SET @TOPLAM_SAYI = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE[TARİH] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())))
SET @TOPLAM_SAYI = '<h3><span style="color: #000000;">'+ CONVERT (NVARCHAR, @TOPLAM_SAYI) + ' adet mail.</span></h3>'


--ODEME TALEP---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET @ODEME_TALEP_INSERT =
N'<h3><span style="color: #000000;">ÖDEME TALEP</span></h3>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">TARİH</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">CLCARD LOGREF</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">FİRMA KODU</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">FİRMA ADI</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">MAIL</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">BCC</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">firmamiz YETKİLİ</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">firmamiz POZİSYON</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">firmamiz İLETİŞİM TELEFONU</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">firmamiz EPOSTA ADRESİ</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">ORT. VADE</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ</th>
<th style="width: 200px; background-color: #defeff;">TOPLAM BORÇ BAKİYENİZ</th>
</tr>' +
CAST ( ( 
SELECT 
td = CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),[TARİH],104), '',
td = ISNULL ([CLCARD LOGREF],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([FİRMA KODU],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([FİRMA ADI],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([MAIL],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([BCC],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([firmamiz YETKİLİ],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([firmamiz POZİSYON],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([firmamiz İLETİŞİM TELEFONU],'-'), '',
td = ISNULL ([firmamiz EPOSTA ADRESİ],'-'), '',
td = CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),[ORT. VADE],104), '',
td = CONVERT (NVARCHAR,[ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ]), '',
td = FORMAT (ROUND ([VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI],2), 'N' , 'de-DE'), '',
td = FORMAT (ROUND ([VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ],2), 'N' , 'de-DE'), '',
td = FORMAT (ROUND ([TOPLAM BORÇ BAKİYENİZ],2), 'N' , 'de-DE'), ''

FROM TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE
[TARİH] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))

FOR XML PATH ('tr'), TYPE ) as NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</tbody></table>';

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET @BODY_INSERT = @TOPLAM_SAYI + ' <br/> ' + @ODEME_TALEP_INSERT + ' <br/> ' + '' ; -- Line Break
SET @KONU_INSERT = CONVERT (NVARCHAR (MAX), GETDATE(),104) + ' TARİHLİ ÖDEME TALEP MAİL'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'AutoMail',
@recipients = 'gokhanerdogdu@firmamiz-.com',
--@recipients = '',
--@copy_recipients = '',
@subject = @KONU_INSERT,
@body = @BODY_INSERT,  
@body_format = 'HTML'

END
  --WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:20' 
--CURSOR---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE 
@CRSR_TARİH DATETIME,
@CRSR_CLCARD_LOGREF INT, 
@CRSR_FİRMA_KODU NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@CRSR_FİRMA_ADI NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@CRSR_MAIL NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@CRSR_BCC NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@CRSR_firmamiz_YETKİLİ NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CRSR_firmamiz_POZİSYON NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CRSR_firmamiz_İLETİŞİM_TELEFONU NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CRSR_firmamiz_EPOSTA_ADRESİ NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CRSR_ORT_VADE DATE, 
@CRSR_ORT_GECİKME_GÜNÜ INT,
@CRSR_VADESİ_GEÇEN_ÖDEME_TUTARI NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CRSR_VADESİ_GELMEMİŞ_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CRSR_TOPLAM_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ NVARCHAR(MAX)

--// Cursor oluşturuluyor.
DECLARE PersonelCursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR             
--// Cursor'un temsil edeceği veri kümesini getirecek olan sorguyu belirtiliyoruz.
--QUERY----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
[TARİH],
[CLCARD LOGREF], 
[FİRMA KODU], 
[FİRMA ADI], 
[MAIL], 
[BCC], 
[firmamiz YETKİLİ], 
[firmamiz POZİSYON], 
[firmamiz İLETİŞİM TELEFONU], 
[firmamiz EPOSTA ADRESİ], 
[ORT. VADE], 
[ORT. GECİKME GÜNÜ], 
[VADESİ GEÇEN ÖDEME TUTARI], 
[VADESİ GELMEMİŞ BORÇ BAKİYENİZ], 
[TOPLAM BORÇ BAKİYENİZ] 
FROM [TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
[TARİH] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
--QUERY SON--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--// Cursor açılarak kaynak tüketimi başlatılıyor.
OPEN PersonelCursor
--// Sıradaki veri yakalanıyor ve hafızaya alınıyor. O anki veri 'PersonelCursor' tarafından temsil ediliyor ve kolon değerleri ilgili değişkenlere sıralı bir şekilde atanıyor.
FETCH NEXT FROM PersonelCursor INTO 
@CRSR_TARİH,
@CRSR_CLCARD_LOGREF, 
@CRSR_FİRMA_KODU, 
@CRSR_FİRMA_ADI, 
@CRSR_MAIL, 
@CRSR_BCC, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_YETKİLİ, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_POZİSYON, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_İLETİŞİM_TELEFONU, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_EPOSTA_ADRESİ, 
@CRSR_ORT_VADE, 
@CRSR_ORT_GECİKME_GÜNÜ,
@CRSR_VADESİ_GEÇEN_ÖDEME_TUTARI, 
@CRSR_VADESİ_GELMEMİŞ_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ, 
@CRSR_TOPLAM_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ
--// İşlem başarılı ise @@FETCH_STATUS değişken değeri '0' ise işlem başarılıdır ve bir sonraki kayıt var demektir.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

  --WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:20' 

DECLARE @ErrorMsg nvarchar(400)

IF (SELECT count(*) FROM [TBL_ÖDEME_TALEP_MAİL]) = 0

BEGIN
    SET     @ErrorMsg = 'BOŞ'
    SELECT  @ErrorMsg Err
    RETURN 
END



BEGIN 

DECLARE @tarih DATETIME;

DECLARE @firma_adi NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ort_vade DATE;
DECLARE @ort_gecikme_gunu INT;
DECLARE @vadesi_gecen_odeme_tutari float;
DECLARE @vadesi_gelmemis_borc_bakiyeniz float;
DECLARE @toplam_borc_bakiyeniz float;
DECLARE @firmamiz_yetkili  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @firmamiz_pozisyon  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @firmamiz_iletisim_telefonu  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @firmamiz_eposta_adresi  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;



DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @İŞ_ORTAKLARI NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @BODY_İŞ_ORTAKLARI NVARCHAR(MAX);



SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF



SET @tarih = @CRSR_TARİH

SET @firma_adi = ISNULL (@CRSR_FİRMA_ADI,'-')
SET @ort_vade = ISNULL (@CRSR_ORT_VADE,'-')
SET @ort_gecikme_gunu = ISNULL (@CRSR_ORT_GECİKME_GÜNÜ,'-')
SET @vadesi_gecen_odeme_tutari = ISNULL (@CRSR_VADESİ_GEÇEN_ÖDEME_TUTARI,'-')
SET @vadesi_gelmemis_borc_bakiyeniz  = ISNULL (@CRSR_VADESİ_GELMEMİŞ_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ,'-')
SET @toplam_borc_bakiyeniz = ISNULL (@CRSR_TOPLAM_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ,'-')
SET @firmamiz_yetkili = ISNULL (@CRSR_firmamiz_YETKİLİ,'-')
SET @firmamiz_pozisyon = ISNULL (@CRSR_firmamiz_POZİSYON,'-')
SET @firmamiz_iletisim_telefonu = ISNULL (@CRSR_firmamiz_İLETİŞİM_TELEFONU,'-')
SET @firmamiz_eposta_adresi = ISNULL (@CRSR_firmamiz_EPOSTA_ADRESİ,'-')

SET @BODY =

'
<p><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>firmamiz - Bilgilendirme Servisi</strong></span></p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 32.3702%;">
<h3><a title="firmamiz -" href="https://firmamiz-.com/en/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="color: #e3221b;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/logo.png" alt="" width="258" height="70" /></span></a></h3>
</td>
<td style="width: 28.6851%;">
<h3><span style="color: #e3221b;"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span><a style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center;" href="https://eticaret.firmamiz-.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://eticaret.firmamiz-.com/Uploads/EditorUploads/logo_e_firmamiz.jpg" alt="E-Ticaret" width="197" height="66" /></a></h3>
</td>
<td style="width: 38.2327%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Bas%CC%A7liksiz-1.png" alt="" width="132" height="92" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h3 style="padding-left: 40px; text-align: left;"><span style="color: #e2231c;"><strong>'+@firma_adi+'</strong></span></h3>
<p>'+FORMAT (@tarih, 'dd.MM.yyyy')+' tarihi itibari ile vadesi ge&ccedil;en <span style="color: #e2231c;"><strong>'+FORMAT(ROUND (@vadesi_gecen_odeme_tutari,2), 'N' , 'de-DE')+' TL</strong></span> &ouml;denmemiş borcunuz bulunmaktadır.<br />Vadesi ge&ccedil;en borcunuzu en kısa s&uuml;rede &ouml;demenizi rica eder iyi &ccedil;alışmalar dileriz.</p>
<table style="width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; float: left; height: 72px;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 27.916%; height: 18px;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;">'+@firmamiz_yetkili+'</span></em></strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 2.21892%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 69.865%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 27.916%; height: 18px;">Pozisyon</td>
<td style="width: 2.21892%; height: 18px;">:</td>
<td style="width: 69.865%; height: 18px;">'+@firmamiz_pozisyon+'</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 27.916%; height: 18px;">İletişim Telefonu</td>
<td style="width: 2.21892%; height: 18px;">:</td>
<td style="width: 69.865%; height: 18px;">'+@firmamiz_iletisim_telefonu+'</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 27.916%; height: 18px;">E-posta Adresi</td>
<td style="width: 2.21892%; height: 18px;">:</td>
<td style="width: 69.865%; height: 18px;">'+@firmamiz_eposta_adresi+'</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100%;">* &Ouml;deme yaptıysanız ya da tarafınıza bildirilen bakiye bilgileri ile hesaplarınız arasında tutarsızlık var ise tarafımıza bilgi vermenizi rica ederiz.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #000000;">'+FORMAT (@tarih, 'dd.MM.yyyy')+' Tarihi itibariyle</span></p>
<table style="height: 47px; width: 344px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #cfc6c6; border-style: dashed; border-color: #e2231c; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 229.047px;">Ort. Vade</td>
<td style="width: 107.953px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #e2231c;"><strong>'+FORMAT (@ort_vade, 'dd.MM.yyyy')+'</strong></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 47px;">
<td style="width: 229.047px; height: 17px;">Ort. Gecikme G&uuml;n&uuml;</td>
<td style="width: 107.953px; height: 17px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #e2231c;"><strong>'+CONVERT (NVARCHAR,@ort_gecikme_gunu)+' G&Uuml;N</strong></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 36px;">
<td style="width: 229.047px; height: 10px;">Vadesi Ge&ccedil;en &Ouml;deme Tutarı</td>
<td style="width: 107.953px; height: 10px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #e2231c;"><strong>'+FORMAT(ROUND (@vadesi_gecen_odeme_tutari,2), 'N' , 'de-DE')+' TL</strong></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 72px;">
<td style="width: 229.047px; height: 10px;">Vadesi Gelmemiş Bor&ccedil; Bakiyeniz</td>
<td style="width: 107.953px; height: 10px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>'+FORMAT(ROUND (@vadesi_gelmemis_borc_bakiyeniz,2), 'N' , 'de-DE')+' TL</strong></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 54px;">
<td style="width: 229.047px; height: 10px;">TOPLAM BOR&Ccedil; BAKİYENİZ</td>
<td style="width: 107.953px; height: 10px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>'+FORMAT(ROUND (@toplam_borc_bakiyeniz,2), 'N' , 'de-DE')+' TL</strong></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><strong><span style="color: #005db9;">&Ouml;deme yapabileceğiniz iban bilgilerimiz;</span></strong></p>
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #cfdae6; border-style: dotted;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;" height="20"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>Banka Adı</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>Banka Şubesi&nbsp;</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>Şube Kodu&nbsp;</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>Hesap No&nbsp;</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>IBAN&nbsp;</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 16.3701%; text-align: center;"><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>D&ouml;viz T&uuml;r&uuml;&nbsp;</strong></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;" height="20">GARANTİ&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">İMES TİCARİ&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">1616</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">6298921</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">TR69 0006 2001 6160 0006 2989 21</td>
<td style="width: 16.3701%; text-align: center;">TL&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;" height="20">AKBANK&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">İMES SANAYİ&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">546</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">81486</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">TR32 0004 6005 4688 8000 0814 86&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.3701%; text-align: center;">TL&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;" height="20">İŞBANK&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">İMES SANAYİ&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">1381</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">13083</td>
<td style="width: 16.726%; text-align: center;">TR90 0006 4000 0011 3810 0130 83&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 16.3701%; text-align: center;">TL&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
';

SET @İŞ_ORTAKLARI =

'
<p><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong>İş Ortaklarımız;</strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #005db9;"><img style="color: #000000; text-align: center;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-schneider-electric.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000; text-align: center;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Telemecanique-Sensor-Logo.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-banner.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-harting.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-weg.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></span><span style="color: #005db9;"><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/cembre.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-relpol.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-katlax.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/weid_%C3%87al%C4%B1%C5%9Fma-Y%C3%BCzeyi-1.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/x_Calisma-Yuzeyi-1.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></span><span style="color: #005db9;"><img style="color: #000000;" src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-klemsan-01-2.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><strong><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-esa-automation.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-enda.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-entes.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/firmamiz---is-ortaklari-wago.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></strong></span><span style="color: #005db9;"><strong><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/logo-1.png" alt="" width="100" height="24" /><img src="https://firmamiz-.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cofaso.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></strong></span></p>
'

SET @BODY_İŞ_ORTAKLARI = @BODY + ' <br/> ' +  @İŞ_ORTAKLARI + ' <br/> ' + '' ; -- Line Break





EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'AutoMail',
@recipients = @CRSR_MAIL,
--@recipients = 'gokhanerdogdu@firmamiz-.com',
@copy_recipients = @CRSR_firmamiz_EPOSTA_ADRESİ,
@blind_copy_recipients = @CRSR_BCC,
@subject = @firma_adi,
@body = @BODY_İŞ_ORTAKLARI,  
@body_format = 'HTML'

END

  --WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:20' 

    -- Sıradaki veriye geçilir ve tekrardan cursor üzerinden kolon değerleri ilgili değişkenlere atanır.
    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonelCursor INTO 
@CRSR_TARİH,
@CRSR_CLCARD_LOGREF, 
@CRSR_FİRMA_KODU, 
@CRSR_FİRMA_ADI, 
@CRSR_MAIL, 
@CRSR_BCC, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_YETKİLİ, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_POZİSYON, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_İLETİŞİM_TELEFONU, 
@CRSR_firmamiz_EPOSTA_ADRESİ, 
@CRSR_ORT_VADE, 
@CRSR_ORT_GECİKME_GÜNÜ,
@CRSR_VADESİ_GEÇEN_ÖDEME_TUTARI, 
@CRSR_VADESİ_GELMEMİŞ_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ, 
@CRSR_TOPLAM_BORÇ_BAKİYENİZ
  END
    --WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:20' 
--// Cursor kapatılıyor.
CLOSE PersonelCursor
--// Tarafımıza ayrılan hafızayı boşaltıyoruz.
DEALLOCATE PersonelCursor
```

Comment: Do you know what a [mcve] is?

Comment: Can you send a test email. Right click on Management-Database Mail. Click on Send Test Email.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the database mail profile configuration, not your code.

Comment: thank you all. I increased the number of retries and the problem was solved.